# XOrg Wallpaper Black and Not Redrawing

Tags: centos, xorg, amd-graphics

I recently updated a CentOS 7 box and encountered a strange issue with my XOrg background not redrawing. I'm at a loss as to where to start diagnosing this issue.

My machine is an AMD E-350D with integrated Radeon graphics running CentOS 7. I use it primarily as a Samba server but occasionally use it as a desktop running GNOME and Cinnamon. After completion of a recent `yum update` I am experiencing an issue with corruption of the wallpaper of my desktop. The configured wallpaper flashes briefly, then is replaced with a black screen and does not redraw. Any UI graphics that get drawn on the desktop such as by dragging icons or selection boxes remain on the screen, basically giving you the "IT Crowd" effect if you are familiar with the final part of the intro of that television show:

[image: Desktop displaying a black screen with a corrupted desktop]

Thinking my user preferences could have been corrupted, I have tried creating a new user and the issue is still present, even if I use a GNOME desktop.

Basically everything was updated so I am at a loss as to where to start. The list is too long to post here. I do not think it is a graphic driver problem since applications and web browsing work fine, although they were updated. If anyone could point me in the right direction or has seen this before I would really appreciate it.